# Xcode 5: Adding Decimal Point To iOSCalculator App

Tags: xcode

I can't get all the specifics to match up with my code. Basically I need to add the decimal point function to my app and i don't know how:

Below is my ViewController.h

```
int Method;
int SelectNumber;
float RunningTotal;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

IBOutlet UILabel *Screen;
}

-(IBAction)Number1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number2:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number3:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number4:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number5:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number6:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number7:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number8:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number9:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number0:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)Times: (id)sender;
-(IBAction)Divide: (id)sender;
-(IBAction)Subtract: (id)sender;
-(IBAction)Plus: (id)sender;
-(IBAction)Equals: (id)sender;
-(IBAction)AllClear: (id)sender;
-(IBAction)Decimal:(id)sender;

@end
```

And here is my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)Number1:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber *10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 1;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}

-(IBAction)Number2:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber *10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 2;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number3:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber *10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 3;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number4:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber *10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 4;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number5:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber *10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 5;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number6:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber *10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 6;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number7:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber *10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 7;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number8:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber *10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 8;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number9:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber *10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 9;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number0:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber *10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 0;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}

-(IBAction)Times: (id)sender{

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {

        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    }

    else{

        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }

    Method = 1;
    SelectNumber = 0;
}
-(IBAction)Divide: (id)sender{

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {

        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    }

    else{

        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }

    Method = 2;
    SelectNumber = 0;
}
-(IBAction)Subtract: (id)sender{

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {

        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    }

    else{

        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }


    Method = 3;
    SelectNumber = 0;
}
-(IBAction)Plus: (id)sender{

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {

        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    }

    else{

        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }


    Method = 4;
    SelectNumber = 0;
}
-(IBAction)Equals: (id)sender{

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {

        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    }

    else{

        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
            RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
            break;
        case 4:
            RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


}

Method = 0;
SelectNumber = 0;
Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", RunningTotal];

}
-(IBAction)AllClear: (id)sender{

    Method = 0;
    RunningTotal = 0;
    SelectNumber = 0;

    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];

}
-(IBAction)Decimal:(id)sender{

  //I Need this Bit

}
```

And all the viewdidload stuff is below but i thought that was irrelevant

Comment: Do you know what an `Integer` is?   You want to change your calculator to use floating point math. What variable is your result stored in?  What type is it now? What type should it be? Is this your first day programming?

Answer (score 0):

You had wrote switch statement multiple times which makes your code to be longer. Just on every arithmetic operator button give a method number. On clicking equals button make the switch statement to execute. So that your code will become too less. And please brief your question that what you want.

if you want to have period when the decimal button is clicked.

```
-(IBAction)Decimal:(id)sender{

  Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.0", SelectNumber];

}
```